# How to change font size of the magnitude on a colorbar of a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with colorbar like this, but the magnitude is very small that difficult to see. 
How can I change the font size? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the fontsize, you could set the figure size and dpi, like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=500)`.

Comment: change the dpi is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.random.random(size=(10,10))*1e9
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
b = ax.imshow(a)
cbar = plt.colorbar(b)
cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(40)
```

[image]